# Armadillo inplace_plus significantly slower than "normal" plus operation

Tags: c++, performance, armadillo

I'm writing a program with Armadillo 4.500.0 and I experience that inplace calculations such as `s += v * v.t() * q;` are significantly slower than the equivalent `s = s + v * v.t() * q;` where `s`, `v`, and `q` are vectors of appropriate size.

When I run following code it turns out that the inplace version is tons of times slower than the other version, for 500 elements ~480 times slower (5.13sec to 0.011sec) with aggressive optimization (-O3 or -Ofast; Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54)).

```cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

#define N_ELEM 500
#define REP 10000

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    timeval start;
    timeval end;
    double tInplace, tNormal;
    vec s = randu<vec>(N_ELEM);
    vec v = randu<vec>(N_ELEM);
    vec q = randu<vec>(N_ELEM);

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < REP; ++i) {
        s += v * v.t() * q;
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    tInplace = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec + ((end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1e6));

    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < REP; ++i) {
        s = s + v * v.t() * q;
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

    tNormal = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec + ((end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1e6));

    cout << "Inplace: " << tInplace << "; Normal: " << tNormal << " --> " << "Normal is " << tInplace / tNormal << " times faster" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain why the inplace operator performs so much worse although it can use the memory already available, so it wouldn't need to copy anything?

Comment: Testing performance of code compiled without optimizations gives silly results. Test with optimizations and the mystery will probably go away. Some functions are hundreds of times slower when compiled without optimizations.

Comment: @Schwartz: Thank's for the hint, but even with aggressive optimization (-O3 or -Ofast) the performance difference is about 480 times (5.13sec to 0.011sec) (I updated the question accordingly).

Comment: @DavidK - perhaps send a bug report to Armadillo developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting brackets around `v.t() * q` will solve the problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < REP; ++i) {
    s += v * (v.t() * q);
}
```

Using brackets forces the order of evaluation.  The expression `(v.t() * q)` will evaluate to a scalar (technically a 1x1 matrix), which is then used to multiply the `v` vector.  The brackets will also prevent `v * v.t()` turning into an explicit outer product.

Armadillo can work this out automatically when using the `s = s + v * v.t() * q` expression, but it (currently) needs more hints when using the inplace operator `+=`.

Comment: Thank's, works like a charm! It is even ~10% faster than the manual loop I wrote to work around it. But as I have to norm the vector first as well, the manual loop is 1.4 times faster than using either of the two versions because I can calculate the norm of `v` and the dot product `v.t() * q` simultaneously.